# How to wait until text input was 4 character in python 3 and selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium

I using python 3 and web scraping via selenium

I want when I type captcha character in input text after 5 character automatic click on login button

I using a code look like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("Username").send_keys('user')

driver.find_element_by_id("Password").send_keys('pwd')

## driver.find_element_by_id("login_captcha").send_keys(captcha)  Here I typing capctha with hand and I dont want using code

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until()  # Here I dont' know how can waiting until I fixed 5 character it doing to next line

driver.find_element_by_name("button").click()
```

but I don't know how can check do it !

Comment: How are you typing in the characters? Are you doing this manually?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes. I using manually with `chromeDriver`. I want sleep driver until I typed end character captcha

Comment: Can you share more code: how do you enter text to input field?

Comment: @Andersson right, checking my code now. enter to input with hand

Comment: @MikelWilliams, what is the element with `@id="login_captcha"`? Is it input field?

Comment: @Andersson, Yes its `id` input captcha text field

Comment: There is also another way. Since we shouldn't be automating captcha in the first place you can talk to your dev team about implementing test keys as described here:

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#what-happens-to-recaptcha-v1

This will allow you to remove the sleep from your tests and also the need for manual interference in automation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming mentioned input field looks like

```
<input id="login_captcha>
```

You can try below code to wait until 5 characters entered in input field:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: len(driver.find_element_by_id("login_captcha").get_attribute("value")) == 5)
```

Comment: I imported you code but it get error: `TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()`

Comment: Oh, yep. Updated